# Python Django Mysql Expected in: flat namespace

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-2.7, mysql-python

I'm working on a project by using Python(2.7) and Django(1.10) in which I need to use mysql as database, I have installed XAMPP on Mac OSX and created a database.

**Here's my `requirements.txt:`**

```
asn1crypto==0.24.0
certifi==2018.4.16
cffi==1.11.5
chardet==3.0.4
cryptography==2.3
Django==1.10.4
enum34==1.1.6
idna==2.6
ipaddress==1.0.22
MySQL-python==1.2.5
mysqlclient==1.3.6
ndg-httpsclient==0.5.1
passlib==1.7.1
Pillow==5.1.0
pusher==2.0.1
pyasn1==0.4.4
pycparser==2.18
pyOpenSSL==18.0.0
requests==2.18.4
securetrading==1.0.14
six==1.11.0
stripe==1.82.1
urllib3==1.22
```

When I run my Django application by using this command as:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

It through an error like below:

> > Unhandled exception in thread started by  Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> >     "/Users/abdul/multiEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py",
> >     line 226, in wrapper
> >         fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/abdul/multiEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py",
> >     line 113, in inner_run
> >         autoreload.raise_last_exception()   File "/Users/abdul/multiEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py",
> >     line 249, in raise_last_exception
> >         six.reraise(*_exception)   File "/Users/abdul/multiEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py",
> >     line 226, in wrapper
> >         fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/abdul/multiEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/**init**.py",
> >     line 27, in setup
> >         apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)   File "/Users/abdul/multiEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py",
> >     line 108, in populate
> >         app_config.import_models(all_models)   File "/Users/abdul/multiEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py",
> >     line 199, in import_models
> >         self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/**init**.py",
> >     line 37, in import_module
> >         **import**(name)   File "/Users/abdul/multiEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py",
> >     line 4, in 
> >         from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager   File
> >     "/Users/abdul/multiEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py",
> >     line 52, in 
> >         class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):   File "/Users/abdul/multiEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py",
> >     line 119, in **new**
> >         new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))   File "/Users/abdul/multiEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py",
> >     line 316, in add_to_class
> >         value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)   File "/Users/abdul/multiEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py",
> >     line 214, in contribute_to_class
> >         self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())   File
> >     "/Users/abdul/multiEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/**init**.py",
> >     line 33, in **getattr**
> >         return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)   File "/Users/abdul/multiEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py",
> >     line 211, in **getitem**
> >         backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])   File "/Users/abdul/multiEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py",
> >     line 115, in load_backend
> >         return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/**init**.py",
> >     line 37, in import_module
> >         **import**(name)   File "/Users/abdul/multiEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py",
> >     line 28, in 
> >         raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e) django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb
> >     module:
> >     dlopen(/Users/abdul/multiEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so,
> >     2): Symbol not found: _mysql_affected_rows   Referenced from:
> >     /Users/abdul/multiEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so
>
> Expected in: flat namespace  in
>
> /Users/abdul/multiEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so

Comment: `pip uninstall MySQL-python` and then
`brew install mysql` and install mysql after that `pip install MySQL-python`

Comment: what do you mean by "install mysql after that "?